# CRA project node v14.17.0 - Loading PostCSS "postcss-preset-env" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'node:vm'

Tags: reactjs, postcss-loader, cra

I'm getting the following error when trying to start a CRA project running with node 14.17.0 -> Loading PostCSS "postcss-preset-env" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'node:vm'

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/app.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WGBI.jpg).rules[0].oneOf[5].use[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WGBI.jpg)!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WGBI.jpg).rules[0].oneOf[5].use[2]!./src/app.css)

Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Loading PostCSS "postcss-preset-env" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'node:vm'
Require stack:

- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/@csstools/postcss-trigonometric-functions/dist/index.cjs
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/postcss-preset-env/dist/index.cjs
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/utils.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/dist/index.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/react-app-rewired/overrides/webpack.js
- /Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/node_modules/react-app-rewired/scripts/start.js

(@/Users/niltonxd/Workspace/harv-Harvest-frontend/src/app.css)

```
{
  "name": "harvest-front",
  "version": "1.7.4",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "antd": "^4.18.7",
    "apexcharts": "^3.19.2",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "har-validator": "^5.1.5",
    "history": "4.10.1",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.9",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "password-validator": "^5.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "query-string": "^6.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.7",
    "react-clear-cache": "^1.2.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "npm:@hot-loader/react-dom@^17.0.2",
    "react-error-boundary": "^3.1.4",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-leaflet": "2.8.0",
    "react-number-format": "^4.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^1.0.1",
    "redis": "^3.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "url-search-params": "^1.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.4",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "antd": "4.2.4",
    "immer": "9.0.6",
    "property-expr": "2.0.3",
    "ansi-html": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-html-community/-/ansi-html-community-0.0.8.tgz",
    "glob-parent": "6.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "npm install react-dom@17.0.2 --save",
    "sonar": "node sonar-project.js",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "start::dev": "env-cmd -e dev react-app-rewired start",
    "start::qa": "env-cmd -e qa react-app-rewired start",
    "start::np": "env-cmd -e np react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired --max-old-space-size=8192 build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "test::ci": "react-app-rewired test --coverage=false --ci --watchAll=false --collectCoverageFrom=src/**/*.js --collectCoverageFrom=!src/assets/**/*.js",
    "qa": "PORT=8081 react-scripts start",
    "cy::op": "cypress open",
    "cy::ru": "cypress run",
    "lint": "eslint --max-warnings 0 --ignore-path .gitignore --fix --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src",
    "prettier": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore \"**/*.+(js|json)\"",
    "format": "yarn run prettier -- --write",
    "check-format": "yarn run prettier -- --list-different",
    "validate": "yarn run lint && yarn run test --watchAll --bail",
    "createJob": "node ci/createJob.js",
    "deleteJob": "node ci/deleteJob.js",
    "checkEnvironment": "node ci/checkEnvironment.js",
    "cm": "cz",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "generate:gc": "plop --plopfile ./generators/globalComponent.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^16.0.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^7.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.24",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.6",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.4",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "customize-cra-less-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "cypress": "9.5.2",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^2.3.0",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^3.9.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.3",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.12.2",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jest-axe": "^5.0.1",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.0.8",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "less-vars-to-js": "^1.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
    "plop": "^3.0.5",
    "postcss-normalize": "^10.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "react-extras": "^3.0.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "reactotron-apisauce": "^3.0.0",
    "reactotron-react-js": "^3.3.2",
    "reactotron-redux": "^3.1.1",
    "reactotron-redux-saga": "^4.2.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sonarqube-scanner": "^2.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@components/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/components/$1",
      "@util/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/util/$1",
      "@hooks/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/hooks/$1",
      "@constants/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/constants/$1",
      "@containers/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/containers/$1",
      "@routes/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/routes/$1",
      "@appRedux/(.*)": "<rootDir>/./src/appRedux/$1"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Project error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it appears **this error will temporarily get fixed by installing the latest version of `Node.js`**.

So to fix this, follow these steps:

1. Download and install the [latest `Node.js` version](https://nodejs.org/en/) (recommended for most users, which is `16.15.0` at this moment).
2. Delete your `node_modules` directory from your project. Then you can optionally clear the `npm` cache with `npm cache clean` and verify it with `npm cache verify`.
3. Delete the `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock` file.
4. Reinstall all dependencies and create a new dependency tree using one of the following commands: `npm i`/`npm install`/`yarn`/`yarn install`.

**Note1**: If, in any case, you use `node-sass` in React projects yet, [it is recommended](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/) to use `sass` instead.

**Note2**: In some cases, skipping *step 1* will also work as expected, but I recommend upgrading the `Node.js` version if you do not have other dependencies to prevent that.

**Note3**: As @IvaniltonBezerra mentions in the comments, some apps may throw errors since upgrading `Node.js` to its latest version will also upgrade the `npm`. It may not be compatible with your current dependency tree in production, so to prevent such a problem, you have to use [`--legacy-peer-deps`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config) to restore the old behaviour of the old dependencies.

## Update

This now seems to be permanently solved in [PostCSS Preset Env](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-plugins/pull/407), and following the above steps with skipping step 1 will also solve the problem.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I'm getting some errors but it's because of some peer dependencies from 'and design' I need to solve.

Running `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and `react-app-rewired --max-old-space-size=8192 build` worked, but I need to solve these deps problems!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am using macOS, so some of the commands below are not applicable if we are using Windows or Linux.

I did the following steps to fix the issue:

1. Remove node_modules and clear the npm cache

   ```
    rm -f -r node_modules && npm cache verify
   ```
2. Install the current latest node version (16.15.0)

   ```
    // if you are using nvm to manage the node versioning
    nvm install 16.15.0
    nvm use 16.15.0
   ```

We can access [here](https://bytearcher.com/articles/ways-to-get-the-latest-node.js-version-on-a-mac/) if we are using N, homebrew or MacPorts

3. Reinstall the project packages

   ```
    npm i
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely trying to use create-react-app inside of an image, and the image's current Node version/configurations are crossing wires with create-react-app; that's what I just did by mistake using Docker, and I got the same exact compiling error with node:vm as a missing module

If you're using create-react-app, don't use it while you're in any Docker/Dev Environment images, just run the npx command in your terminal as is (probably helps having node downloaded on your local machine as well)

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Hopefully that helps, I know that solved my problem